# How to extract pages from PDF file

Tags: objective-c, pdf, extract, code-snippets

I am trying, using Objective C to create a code for iOS which lets me extract a number of pages from a pdf file:
I have a PDF file (ex. source.pdf) of 30 pages. I would like create (or better) extract pages from page 3 to page 15 in one **unique** pdf file (ex. result.pdf)

How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at [PdfCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/content/command-line-parameters) for this. It has some command line parameters and option file that might help you.

Comment: In which language?  In Java, [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org) can do this.  See its [PDFSplit](http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandlineutilities/PDFSplit.html) example.

Comment: Actually any decent and not too specialized PDF processing library should be able to do that.

Comment: Sorry I totally forgot !!
In Objective C , for iOS

Comment: I did not find any reason for closing this question..